# JavaFX Canvas clear Circle

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, paint

I am creating a paint program, and every paint program has an eraser tool in it. Therefore, I would like mine to have one as well, the only issue being that I don't know how to clear a circular area in a Canvas using a GraphicsContext. Is there a special paint or effect I can use to be able to clear a circle? I know there already is the `clearRect(x,y,w,h)` method, but I would like a clear circle method so that my eraser can have a circular brush. The code I have so far is this...

```
canvas.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
    if(brushType == ERASER){
        //do something with graphics
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could paint a circle with the same colour as the background. Something along the lines of:

```
canvas.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
  if(brushType == ERASER) {
    context.setFill(backgroundColour);
    context.fillOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), eraserWidth, eraserHeight);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is my background color is transparent? Setting the graphics to a transparent color won't work

Answer (score 0):

A canvas has a pixel writer. You can use that to set the relevant pixels explicitly to any color. Even to a transparent one.